# SyndicationFeed change namespace prefix from a10 to atom

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I am using System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed to create an rss feed from which I get this:

```
<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0"><channel>...</channel></rss>
```

It is all working swimmingly, except for when I [validate my feed](http://validator.w3.org/feed).

The validator complains about the a10 namespace prefix and suggests that I use atom instead. That sounds reasonable.. except I can't see a straightforward way of changing the prefix.

Any ideas on ways of changing the prefix?

Comment: That looks like you have actually output your feed as RSS 2.0, not Atom 1.0 – see the different XML output examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx#code-snippet-3

Comment: Yeah it is rss, that is what I am expecting. For whatever reason the feed validator suggests having a link back to self using the atom namespace so I am just trying to adhere to that. Am adding a link like this - <a10:link href="http://mysite.com/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" /> but then the validator wants a10 to be atom.

Comment: The validator's warning is just a suggestion. There's no reason you *shouldn't* change the prefix, but no valid parser cares about the difference.

Comment: Yeah I know it is just a suggestion, but I would like to change it anyway - if only for finding out how to do it, seems ridiculously difficult right now!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To specify a custom name for the atom extensions you need to disable SerializeExtensionsAsAtom on the feed formatter:

```
var formatter = feed.GetRss20Formatter();
formatter.SerializeExtensionsAsAtom = false;
```

Then you need to add the namespace

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

feed.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName("atom", XNamespace.Xmlns.NamespaceName), atom.NamespaceName);
```

And now you can start using the extensions

```
feed.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement(atom + "link", new XAttribute("href", feedLink), new XAttribute("rel", "self"), new XAttribute("type", "application/rss+xml")));
```

Finally write the feed to the response stream:

```
formatter.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(Response.Output));
```

Comment: This worked very good. Thanks for sharing.