# how to add attributes to syndicationitem elementextension

Tags: syndicationfeed

I am trying to add the media:thumnail element to the atom feed using SyndicationFeed .net class.

my code looks like the below

```
            item.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement("thumbnail",
                                            new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"),
                                            new XAttribute("url", "http://test.com/test.jpg/"),
                                            new XAttribute("width", 200),
                                            new XAttribute("height", 200)
                                        ).CreateReader()
                                    );
```

which outputs as

```
<thumbnail url="http://test.com/test.jpg/" width="200" height="200"          xmlns="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
        </thumbnail>
```

which is still seems to be valid atom feed. But as per client requirement, I want the format to be
`"<media:thumbnail>"`. Could anyone please help me on this?

I even tried like this

```
item.ElementExtensions.Add("thumbnail", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", 10);
```

which outputs as

```
 <media:thumbnail>10</media:thumbnail>
```

but how do I add attributes instead of value?

Answer (score 1):

finally I resolved the xml namespace issue after looking at this...

[[SyndicationFeed change namespace prefix from a10 to atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678635/syndicationfeed-change-namespace-prefix-from-a10-to-atom][1])

for some odd reason I never found that question before I post mine in stackoverflow :(